# Is there any way to make proportionate margins using pure CSS?

Tags: css, margin

Without using a preprocessor like Sass or Less, is there any way to make the margins of a series of elements proportional to their content?

So picture a horizontal navbar with 5 items. The text of each item is different, some are long and some are short, like this:

```
Menu |  Technology and Society | Laurem Ipsum | More Filler Text | Contact
```

I want to space these out proportionately so that the total width is 100% of the parent container and each item gets space and margin proportionate to the amount of text it contains without any of them having too much or too little margin. You can see how there's blank space at the end of the line-- that, for example, should not be there. Too much space is apportioned to the final element.

Is this possible with pure CSS?

If not, how can it be done with Sass or Less?

**Note:** I'm trying to see how this can be done *dynamically*, not by hard-specifying the width percents. I mean is there a way to use CSS so that it just does it automatically no matter how I change the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only way is using `display: table/table-cell` values.

```
<ul>
    <li>Menu
    <li>Technology and Society
    <li>Laurem Ipsum
    <li>More Filler Text
    <li>Contact
</ul>

<style>
    ul {margin: 0; padding: 0; display: table; width: 100%;}
    li {display: table-cell; text-align: center;}
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/og8m3g2m/

Comment: @Aerovistae: `display: table` for UL, `table-cell` for LI. Little updated my answer :)

Comment: Oh I understand, very good...I didn't realize how that worked. Very good indeed. Will accept in 8 minutes.

Comment: @Aerovistae: as a real table cell (`td`) needs a table as a parent, element with `display: table-cell` needs to have a `display: table` parent to achieve the correct result.